# Cuda how do you use a pointer array with __constant__

Tags: arrays, pointers, cuda, int, gpu

I need to dynamically size a int* pointer array that’s queried in every thread of my kernel's instance.

My goal is to make an array of ints in which I won’t know the size of the array until run-time (so it can’t be fixed size).

With that when I do:

```
#include "CudaTest.cuh"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

__constant__ int* deviceArray;

bool CHECK(cudaError_t type)
{
    bool flag = true;
    const cudaError_t error = type;
    if (error != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("\n\n Error: %s:%d, ", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        printf("\n\n code:%d, reason: %s\n", error, cudaGetErrorString(error));
        flag = false;
    }
    return flag;
}

__global__
void myKernel()
{


    //=> // constValue should be 57. But getting an Invalid memory access error here. 
    int constValue = deviceArray[7];
    printf("\n deviceArray[7]; is: %i \n", constValue);

}


int main()
{
    int* hostAry = new int[8]();

    hostAry[7] = 57;
    CHECK(cudaMemcpyToSymbol(deviceArray, hostAry, sizeof(hostAry), 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    myKernel << < 1, 1 >> > ();
    CHECK(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error:
 Error:

code:700, reason: an illegal memory access was encountered

The memory of host array isn't be copied over to deviceArray. 
I'm beating my head against the wall which usually means I don't understand something fundamentally.

Comment: The constant memory variable is a pointer. You haven't allocated any memory anywhere for the devicearray. Obviously that isn't going to work

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Can you  share a simple example in how to allocate this with respect to the example above?

Comment: `__constant__ int deviceArray[8];`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do you use a pointer array with `__constant__`

You don't. It is not possible.

Constant memory must be statically defined at compile time. That means if you want a constant memory array, the size must be defined when you compile the code. There is no way to dynamically allocate constant memory.

The only realistic solution is to define a `__constant__` array to a maximum size, and then a second `__constant__` variable indicating the size of the array which is being used for a given kernel invocation. So something like:

```
__constant__ int devicearray[MAXSIZE];
__constant__ int devicearray_n;
```

Copy the data you need to `devicearray` and the number of elements to `devicearray_n` before launching a kernel.